What are all the Normal Traits of Characters in M&M? (And what of them can be reduced?)
Mutants and Masterminds often has a lot of its information hidden and this is generally one of them that is a bit sad since the Reduced Trait Flaw listed in Enhanced Trait (pg. 159) could be used on Normal Senses to allow for easy access to designing blind or deaf characters. Here's some of them that I've found though some are less RAW than others but I'm looking to complete the list.

Normal Senses 9 (pg. 178)
Increased Mass 1-3 (not RAW, though unless we're saying people are base 50 lbs this is probably the case)
'Extra Limbs' 2 + Enhanced Advantage: Ambidextrous (limited to 1 hand)
Speed 0 (30 ft per 6 seconds makes sense)
Toughness & other Defenses 0 (As durable as 1 inch thick paper)
Stats 0 and the Actions associated with them.
Untrained Skills 0 & their Actions (probably a advantage like Jack of All Trades)


Leaving aside the usual Rule 0 disclaimer that it basically comes down to the GM as to what is a "reduceable" trait, I would agree that there are some base traits which most GMs would agree could be reduced with Reduced Trait, usual caveat that the GM is always free to veto a given suggested reduction if they feel that it's dodgy ("While in his Turret Form, Hlaxxon is reducing his Expertise (Basketweaving) to 0, Vehicles to 0, Technology to 0... Oh, and make my Speed -20 since I'm going to be standing in place...").

Abilities - When building your character, you can reduce any of your abilities down to -5, whereupon that ability is debilitated and is no longer able to be reduced. Note that some forms of debilitation might render the character unable to switch back, since they do things like remove conscious thought.

Past that... it gets iffy. I'd probably agree for reducing defenses with the caveat that I'd look askance for cases where the player is obviously looking to reduce their defenses in a case where it doesn't matter, like a bathroom psychic dropping their Parry and Dodge (or, similarly, an always Insubstantial character), especially to allow changes in caps at lower PLs.
Complications for Disabilities
You mention the possibility of reducing senses. I can't think of any official Green Ronin builds where a sense is removed with Reduced Traits, but there are blind characters where their blindness is built as a Complication. So, instead of gaining points back, you get a Hero Point when you being blind is a significant issue. Similarly, reduced base speed feels more like a Complication (and one often negated by having a Power or Device that bypasses it like a hover-chair, right up until it doesn't). In the 2E Crooks! book (which was itself an adaptation of the 1E book of the same name, based in the META-4 universe that 1E was initially based in) seems to have eliminated a similar Drawback on one of the more elderly villains who had a base speed of 15 feet when not using his magic items. And, of course, 3E largely removed character Drawbacks in favor of Complications.
Mass changes
Honestly, I'm not certain if I'd really call this a penalty. Sometimes, it's handy to be lighter or heavier and sometimes it's an issue.

Rather than GM specification, Reduced Trait is listed in Enhanced Trait's flaws (pg. 159) and defines with little wiggle room what can be reduced at pg 310 under Trait's definition (skills, advantages, abilities, & powers). "Normal Senses" are exactly what they say, a Power that all humans normally have unless reduced, where by extension you can infer all Normal Traits are Traits (why wouldn't they be). It's up to the GM if they don't want you to make a blind character or a 50 lb child, but doing that or putting it under complications when you can simply be Daredevil seems incorrect.

As for Green Ronin builds, the construction of the game makes it very unclear what you are meant to be able to do with it. A lot of the time it feels like the game is made to be used rather than played, so I can understand if RAW wasn't really focused on nor the full implications of their own rules, given what the existence of Variable & optional rules PPless games implies.

Note that PL limits ignore negative scores in one (or more) defenses. To have Toughness 12, a character must be PL 6; a PL 5 character cannot have Toughness 12, even with Dodge and Parry at -2. This isn't clear in your discussion of trade-offs.
